# Some clarifications about Adapter pattern applied to Swing events in Java

Tags: java, swing, events, adapter

I am studying the Java Swing and how to handle an event using the adapter pattern to not do the override of all methods that handle an event.

I have found this short example and I want to know if I have understand it:

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Sketcher {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Sketcher");

    public Sketcher() {
        window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
        window.addWindowListener(new WindowHandler());
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    class WindowHandler extends WindowAdapter {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println("closing");
            window.dispose(); // Release the window resources
            System.exit(0); // End the application
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sketcher();
    }
}
```

What I have understand is:

The **Sketcher** class contains a main method that simply creat a new Sketcher instance.

A **Sketcher** instance create a new **JFrame** object that simply show a frame on monitor.

So when I create a new Sketcher oject is created a new JFrame object.

And here I have my first doubt (that is a genera Java doubt):

**Why I am not creating the JFrame windos object inside the constructor of Sketcher class?**

Whatever, in the constructor, I set some property for the JFrame object and I add a WindowListener to this JFrame.

Now the addWindowListener is a new **WindowHandler** object that is a custom object that handle the windows events.

Now I have two possibilities to handle these events:

1. Use the **classic Listeners**: in this case I have to implement a specific listener for ALL the possibile events that can occur on the JFrame
2. Use an **adapter** (like in this case), so in this case I use an internal class named **WindowHandler** that extends the class **WindowAdapter**. The class **WindowAdapter** contains void methods for all the possibile JFrame events. So in the **WindowHandler** I can define ONLY the method that I want handle and not all the methods.

Is it my reasoning right? Is it a good tutorial example or it present some problem that now I can't see?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, but here are some notes:

1. You asked the question *Why am I not creating the JFrame windows object inside the constructor of Sketcher class?*

   The compiler is doing some work for you; it actually places the initialization of the JFrame inside your constructor. You could also explicitly place the JFrame initialization in your constructor.
2. Your `WindowHandler` class doesn't *have* to be an inner class; it could be any class that implements `WindowListener` or extends `WindowAdapter`.
3. The `XXXAdapter` classes in AWT and Swing is just a naming convention for classes that provide no-operation convenience implementations of the related interface. They aren't really adapters (see below).
4. Your `main` implementation doesn't *have* to be in your frame's class; it could be in any class.

Generally, we don't like to create a bunch of things inside a constructor, especially if there could be side-effects. It's better to provide separate construction and initialization methods.

Specifically for Swing, it's typical to subclass the components to provide for the UI specialization needed for your application, including JFrames. But keep the business logic separate.

Even though the swing class is named `WindowAdapter`, it really isn't adapting anything in the sense of the Adapter pattern. What it does provide is a default no-operation implementation of all methods of the `WindowListener` interface, which allows a developer to override only the method s/he's interested in.

So I would say this is more a study of `overriding` than adaptation; the latter is usually used to [make two incompatible APIs work together](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Comment: Tnx so much !!! My biggest problem is that, reaging online, I have find many tutorial where try to match the Swing adapter with adapter pattern (I don't know why) and I was doing many confusion becase I could not say the relation between Swing adapter and Adapter GOF pattern !!! Why many people on the web try to explain this concept with Adapter GOF pattern is a mistery for me...